# x-axis minimum value to 2 and tickinterval of 6 months using highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I would like to put x-axis starting value as 2.0 and end value to 19.0 with tick-interval as 0.60. When i give difference as 0.60 its starts from 1.8 and ends at 19.2 even if i give minimum and maximum value. Please help me to sort out this!

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
    },
    xAxis: {
        startOnTick: true,
        min:2.0,
        step: 2,
        max: 19.0,
        startOnTick: true,
        endOnTick: true,
        tickInterval: 0.60
    },

    series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
    }]
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/aparnaunny/6mHfw/1/

^ This is what i tried.

Thanks,
Aparna Unny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you want a range of size 17 (19 - 2) with a tickInterval of 0.6. 17 doesn't devide equally by 0.6, so the chart has to adjust the min/max.

Also, 2 isn't a multiple of 0.6, so startOnTick must be false if you want to start at 2.

Either pick a different ticker interval (e.g. 0.5) or chose a min/max range which devides eqully by 0.6 e.g. 2 / 19.2

```
  xAxis: {
        min:2.0,
        step: 2,
        max: 19.0,
        startOnTick: true,
        endOnTick: true,
        tickInterval: 0.50
    },
```

or

```
    xAxis: {
        step:2,
        min:2.0,
        max: 19.4,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        tickInterval: 0.60
    },
```

Comment: Thanks Steve :). Let me go through this.